Proving that $\int_{1}^{n} \ln(x) \, dx \leq \ln(n!) \leq \int_{1}^{n+1} \ln(x) \, dx$ by comparing areas
I have to prove by comparing areas that,$$\text{For } n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad \int_{1}^{n} \ln(x) \, dx \leq \ln(n!) \leq \int_{1}^{n+1} \ln(x) \, dx$$
I tried graphing $\ln(n!) = \int_{1}^{n!} \frac{1}{t} \, dt$
but I can't easily prove that the inequality holds up.
I also notice that $$\ln(n!) = \ln(2) + \ln(3) + \cdots + \ln(n)$$ but I'm not sure how to use that to my advantage. Any hints?

It is better to calculate the integrals directly than to look at the linked answer.

Try drawing rectangles with basis in the $x$ axis, with bottom going from $k$ to $k+1$, and height $ln(k)$, with $k$ ranging from $1$ to $n$. Then the second inequality becomes easy to see (by making use of the thing you noticed). The first inequality you can get similarly, but the heights of the rectangles should be $ln(k+1)$, with bottom going from $k$ to $k+1$, with $k$ ranging from $0$ to $n-1$ - I believe this should work.
